# Powershell commands to txt

Tags: powershell

Goal

Chain commands together and then Out-File to a filename.txt

For example
netstat -s;netstat -r;netstat -bona;netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state;Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime

Display on Screen while writing to file

I know there is a way but when I issue | Out-File

There is this other method but man is the code long
"netstat -s>>filename.txt";netstat -r>>filename.txt";netstat -bona>>filename.txt" ...

Looking for a quick one-liner to perform this operation.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a one-liner. But you could do this easily by assigning the command to a variable then outputting it to a .txt file

```
$output = netstat -s;netstat -r;netstat -bona;netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state;Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime

$output | out-file test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a scriptblock, and immediately invoke it, then pipe to `Tee-Object` to both write to file and to the pipeline (and thus the screen unless you otherwise redirect it).

```
{netstat -s;netstat -r;netstat -bona;netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state;Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime}.Invoke() | Tee-Object -FilePath FileName.txt
```

Comment: TheMadTechnician / jRider - Thank you to both of you.  Even though I will be using the Tee-Object method - I knew there was an answer to solving this equation.